# Не компилируется пример использующий библиотеку boost

Tags: c++, boost

Установил библиотеку boost на свою ubuntu командой `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`.

Не компилируется пример из википедии:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hello_world()
{
  cout << "Здравствуй, мир, я - thread!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  boost::thread my_thread(&hello_world);
  my_thread.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
ch.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
ch.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
ch.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int, char const*)':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC2EiPKc[_ZN5boost16thread_exceptionC5EiPKc]+0x23): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data_base::thread_data_base()':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail16thread_data_baseC5Ev]+0x1e): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::thread::start_thread()':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv[_ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv]+0x24): undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::thread::~thread()':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6threadD2Ev[_ZN5boost6threadD5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `boost::thread::detach()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::thread::get_id() const':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost6thread6get_idEv[_ZNK5boost6thread6get_idEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::thread::native_handle()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::thread::join()':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6thread4joinEv[_ZN5boost6thread4joinEv]+0x88): undefined reference to `boost::thread::join_noexcept()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o: In function `boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::~thread_data()':
ch.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED2Ev[_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEED5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base()'
/tmp/ccq2zeuG.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE[_ZTIN5boost6detail11thread_dataIPFvvEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Как компилировать программы, использующие boost ?

Comment: Ну вот, на моем примере можете сказать какую команду вводить ?

Comment: `g++  -lboost_thread -lboost_system ch.cpp -o ch`

Comment: Те же самые ошибки выдает

Answer (score 3):

Это ошибки линкера, а не компилера: линкер не знает где взять реализацию использующихся функций. Нужно указать линкеру какие библиотеки нужно подключать, где они лежат и так далее. Поскольку вы не указали как именно вы собираете программу, конкретные шаги по исправлению указать проблематично.

Comment: Ну если шаги по исправлению указать проблематично, приведите пожалуйста шаги с первого до последнего, как линковать и компилировать. Спасибо.
@ВладимирМартьянов

Comment: @Антон вам сложно указать как именно вы программу собираете, а мне писать трактат на 16 страниц? Славный подход... Но я воздержусь.